# Upload to none public or private folders when using managed_file field type

Tags: 7, files

Is there a way to use an arbitrary directory for uploading a file? One that is not the public or private folder? I do not mind if it doesn't save a record in the Database.

```
$form['upload_logo'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Upload a Logo'),
    '#weight' => 18,
    '#upload_location' => drupal_realpath('sites/all/files/images/logos'),
    '#upload_validators'  => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg')),
);
```

The current code returns this message:
The file could not be uploaded, because the destination "Path Generated By drupal_realpath()" is invalid.

Comment: Have you tried `'#upload_location' => 'file:///path/to/file.ext'`?

Comment: Good thinking, I did not try that.
Got this message:
The upload directory file://sites/all/files/images/logos for the file field could not be created or is not accessible. 

A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled.

When looking at the reports. I am going to check my folder permissions again.

Comment: Try making the path absolute (`file:///var/www/...`)

Comment: Figured it out. I dug into the code a little bit and discovered that it is looking for a valid stream wrapper. The public:// and private://  steam wrappers ship with Drupal while file:/// does not. I created my own by following these instructions and it worked perfectly. https://www.drupal.org/node/560424

Thanks again for the tip, could not have figured it out without your lead.